# ExtJS Menu parameter to pass

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, menu

I am creating an ExtJS MVC application with a dynamic menu. I have several menu elements which will call the same screen (set an active card in a layout) but need to pass a different value in as a parameter each time. So that one card can display different data depending on the parameter which will act as a filter.

my menu elements have a click listener:

```
listeners: {
    itemclick: function(view, record, item, index, e){
    Ext.getCmp('contentpanel').layout.setActiveItem(record.getId());
    }
}
```

the record Id will be the card I am setting as active.
How can I pass along a parameter to the card?

Answer (score 0):

You could just add another attribute to the Panel if you want. For example:

```
Ext.define('YourApp.view.YourCardPanel' ,{
  extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
  id: 'contentpanel',
  alias : 'widget.yourcardpanel',
  layout: 'card',
  newParam: null, // Just to know that this attribute exists but there is no need to declare it.
  items: [],
  changeLayout: function(){
     if (this.newParam == 'new value')  {
         // Do your stuff
     }
  }
});
```

And then you could change the value of that parameter.

```
listeners: {
  itemclick: function(view, record, item, index, e){
    var cardPanel = Ext.getCmp('contentpanel');
    cardPanel.newParam = 'new value';
    cardPanel.changeLayout();      
    cardPanel.layout.setActiveItem(record.getId());
  }
}
```